# databinding to get only properties. UI update. BindingSource

Tags: .net, data-binding

I bound to class' get only properties (for example)

```
    public bool IsRunning
    {
     get 
      {
         return myThread!=null && myThread.IsAlive;
      }
    }
```

using binding source.  And controls bound to it do not reflect changes on get only properties.
I thought I could implement INotifyPropertyChanged interface, but that seems to work only on setter 
(because you need to raise PropertyChanged event manually when that property changes).
Right now I have stupid timer running and polling for changes.  What could I do to automate controls (or binding source for that matter) to reflect property values dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep implementing INotifyPropertyChanged, but raise the event when your thread starts and dies
ie:

```
bool _isRunning;
bool IsRunning{
get{return _isRunning;}
set{
  _isRunning=value;
  Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsRunning"))));
}

void foo(){
 myThread=new Thread(doWork).Start();
}

void doWork(){
  IsRunning=true;
  try{
    // stuff
  }finally{
    IsRunning=false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thread.Abort raises a ThreadAbortException on the target thread. I edited the answer to take care of this. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx